# Comparing foreign keys in entity framework 3.5

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an organization table with following structure

```
[dbo].[Organizations](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Phone] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
[Fax] [nchar](11) NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[URL] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EstablishedYear] [nchar](4) NULL,
[CategoryId] [int] NULL,
[RegionId] [int] NULL,
[CityId] [int] NULL,
[ProvinceId] [int] NULL,
[CountryId] [int] NULL,
[ImageFileName] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

because I'm using entity framework 3.5,
I've used a partial class to add foreign key properties (for countryid, provinceid ,...)

```
  public partial class Organization
{
    public int? CountryId
    {
        get
        {
            if (CountryReference.EntityKey == null)
                return null;
            return (int)CountryReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value != -1)
                CountryReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("Entities.Countries", "CountryId", value);
            else
                CountryReference.EntityKey = null;
        }
    }
```

}

Now I have a query but it throws an exception:

Query:

```
  if (Enumerable.Any(ctx.Organizations.Where(s => s.CountryId==  Organization.CountryId && s.ProvinceId == Organization.ProvinceId && s.CityId == Organization.CityId && s.Name == Organization.Name)))
```

Exception:

```
The specified type member 'CountryId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

I just want to compare navigation properties, any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the solution:

```
 if (Enumerable.Any(ctx.Organizations.AsEnumerable().
         Where(s => s.CountryId == Organization.CountryId && 
                    s.ProvinceId == Organization.ProvinceId && 
                    s.CityId == Organization.CityId && 
                    s.Name == Organization.Name)))
```

befor using where condition i used AsEnumerable() method.

Comment: -1 this will load your *ENTIRE* `Organizations` table from the database - @Ladislav Mrnka's solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use properties defined in partial class in linq-to-entities query. You must use navigation property directly:

```
ctx.Organizations.Where(o => o.Country.Id == someCountryId);
```

Comment: tanks for your reply, some times, Country is null and i should check it before accessing country.id, and this is a lot of coding, is there a better solution?

Comment: You don't need to check it in linq-to-entities query.

Comment: it throws null reference exception when country is null

Comment: how i can use custom function in where linq method?

Comment: @r.zarei: This code, as written, will not throw a null reference exception.  How are you using it?